# How do you create ProjectApiRoot as Customer in Commercetools

Tags: java, api, basic-authentication, commercetools

I can create a ProjectApiRoot using the Java SDK and perform requests with that using the following code:

```
private static ProjectApiRoot createProjectClient() {
    ProjectApiRoot apiRoot = ApiRootBuilder.of()
            .defaultClient(ClientCredentials.of()
                    .withClientId(System.getenv("CTP_CLIENT_ID"))
                    .withClientSecret(System.getenv("CTP_CLIENT_SECRET"))
                    .build(),
                    ServiceRegion.GCP_EUROPE_WEST1)
            .build(System.getenv("CTP_PROJECT_KEY"))
    return apiRoot
}
```

However, I would like to authorize as a specific customer (email and password) and interact with the Commercetools API using the customer. The following code throws an error:

```
private static ProjectApiRoot createCustomerClient() {
    def tokenUri = "https://auth.europe-west1.gcp.commercetools.com/oauth/*CTP_PROJECT_KEY*/customers/token"
    def projectKey = System.getenv("CTP_PROJECT_KEY")
    def scopes = System.getenv("CTP_SCOPES")

    def credentials = ClientCredentials.of()
            .withClientId("*email*")
            .withClientSecret("*password*")
            .withScopes(scopes)
            .build()

    def apiRootBuilder = ApiRootBuilder.of()
            .withApiBaseUrl("https://api.europe-west1.gcp.commercetools.com")
            .withClientCredentialsFlow(credentials, tokenUri)

    return apiRootBuilder.build(projectKey)
}
```

Error:

```
io.vrap.rmf.base.client.oauth2.AuthException: detailMessage: Unauthorized
"message" : "Please provide valid client credentials using HTTP Basic Authentication.",
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the withGlobalCustomerPasswordFlow instead of the withClientCredentialsFlow which authenticates the customer prior to doing the request.

But I would advise to do this only in a context where the customer is logging in everytime. Using it in any other context e.g. remembered log in of needs a more sophisticated approach as you need to store the bearer token and refresh token and can't easily use the middleware approach for authenticating the customer but instead do it not as part of an auth flow middleware.

Please see also https://github.com/commercetools/commercetools-sdk-java-v2/tree/main/commercetools/commercetools-sdk-java-api/src/integrationTest/java/commercetools/me

Comment: Thank you. I plan to do it in spock tests where every test starts with logging in.